# How to write this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql

I am not a programmer, just a learner. I am testing something.
I have a table namely test1 which have three columns id , date , status.

I want to change the status of the id which is **10 day old** and have status as **pass or fail or none** to good.

Answer (score 2):

Since you did not specify the RDBMS I will provide an answer for MySQL and SQL Server.  You did not provide many details about your request but you can do the following in MySQL:

```
UPDATE test1
SET status = 'good'
where date < DATE_ADD(now(), interval -10 day)
  AND status IN ('pass', 'fail', 'none');
```

Here is a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6b44/5) with a working example.

In SQL Server your query would be:

```
UPDATE test1
SET status = 'good'
where date < DateAdd(day, -10, getdate())
  AND status IN ('pass', 'fail', 'none');
```

Here is a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6b44/1) with that example.

Comment: It is storing both date and time and in structure it is datetime which function will  be used ??

Comment: If you are storing datetime in the same field, then the same function would be used.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are vague.

This just looks at the pass records and sets them to fail when their date is over 10 days old.

```
update test1
set status = 'fail'
where status = 'pass'
and date < dateadd(d,-10, getdate())
```